# C# JSON parsing from URL with - in classname

Tags: c#, json, parsing

Using C# to parse an JSON array from a url. but there are "-" in the class name, how can U do this?

example:

```
{
  "my-class": [
    {
      "class_name": "1H", 
      "class_room": "201aTD", 
      "day": "26", 
      "month": "10", 
      "period": "2", 
      "subject": "IF", 
      "teacher": "J04", 
      "year": "2015"
    }]
}
```

**EDIT:**

this is my code i try. but i dont get the list back.

```
public void gettimetable(string s) {
            string get = getTimeTable(s);

            JObject o = JObject.Parse(get);

            var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(get);


            TextBox1.Text = (obj.MyClass.ToString());

           // TextBox1.Text=(obj.class_room[0].ToString());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this with [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) by annotating your class using the [`JsonProperty`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_serialization_jsonproperty.htm) attribute:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{   
    var json = "{\"my-class\": [{\"class_name\": \"1H\", 
                                 \"class_room\": \"201aTD\", 
                                 \"day\": \"26\", 
                                 \"month\": \"10\", 
                                 \"period\": \"2\", 
                                 \"subject\": \"IF\", 
                                 \"teacher\": \"J04\", 
                                 \"year\": \"2015\"}]}";

    Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json));
}

public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("my-class")]
    public List<MyClass> MyClass { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass
{
    [JsonProperty("class_name")]
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("class_room")]
    public string ClassRoom { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("day")]
    public string Day { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("month")]
    public string Month { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("period")]
    public string Period { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("subject")]
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("teacher")]
    public string Teacher { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("year")]
    public string Year { get; set; }
}
```